# Name for two pads intentionally adjacent but separated to be solder optionally

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I have seen some boards that leave small adjacent pads that the user can solder in order to connect the two tracks attached permanently.

Is there a standard name for that?

Comment: option jumper or configuration jumper

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solder bridge jumper. Or something similar.

[image]

https://www.pcblibraries.com/forum/footprint-for-solderable-jumper_topic2089.html